# Do I need to download anything else to get grease pencil working in blender 2.8 build?

Tags: grease-pencil

I literally just unzip the zip file and grease pencil doesn't show any strokes when I draw. I watched some grease 2.0 previews and I'm very interested but it doesn't work for me right now. All settings are on default and I reset settings many times also downloaded both x64 versions to try, same result. My brush color is black nothing shows up on white background. What am I doing wrong?

Edited: Just to clarify somethings here, I'm currently using 2.8 not 2.78 build. I know you have to press D then draw, but it currently doesn't work in the 2.8 version that I've downloaded. My 2.78 grease pencil works just fine.

Comment: @cegaton uhm what??? Edited: My grease pencil works fine in 2.78, I'm talking about 2.8 build.

Comment: Yes you need to download a 2.78# officialy supported build instead, not an experimental version under heavy development. Don't expect anything about 2.8 to work reliably or at all this point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a development version of Blender

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos I assumed grease pencil 2.0 is at least functional from one of Daniel M. Lara's videos because he linked a download link. I guess I am wrong.

Comment: That is the problem with development versions, the fact that it was functional some time in the past is no guarantee it is functional now. Code commits are being made all the time, things are changing, features maturing. Some things can break momentarily for a particular build or for extended periods of time without announcement. Either way there is nothing we can do here, and troubleshooting it is a waste of resources, it will be fixed eventually and working as expected for release, that is for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2.8 Grease Pencil Branch is not the same as the builder.blender.org 2.8 branch builds, as you need to compile the separate gpencil branch yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I saw a download link from grease pencil channel on vimeo, and followed the link to download it. I did not see anything related to it however so I assumed its packaged with 2.8 from blender.org. [See this image](http://imgur.com/a/Fx4xW)

Comment: That is misdirected then, as I already checked the main 2.8 on buildbot and it doesn't have the branch as an option - though I do wonder if it can be set up to build it since the build bot accepts instructions